# Mitsubishi Lancer 2017 AUX input

Tags: audio, mitsubishi, lancer, head-unit, factory-flaws

I have a `2017 Mitsubishi Lancer Black Edition CF Auto MY17`.

As shown below, the factory (stock) head unit has an `AUX` option, but there is no 3.5mm AUX input anywhere in the car.

[image]
[image]

The `USB/iPod` option will play audio from my iPhone, but only from the `Music` app; not other apps such as Spotify etc. And the `Bluetooth` option has problems such as stopping music, skipping through songs etc.

I have looked ***extensively*** throughout the car for an AUX input, but found nothing. I've also found a couple posts online from others who have the same problem with the same car.

[Post 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/lancer/comments/84cv7c/does_the_2017_lancer_have_an_aux_input/), [Post 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/mitsubishi/comments/84cxpt/does_the_2017_lancer_have_an_aux_input/)

Previous Lancer models have their AUX input here:

[image]

But as shown, there is only a USB input and cigarette lighter input; no AUX.

---

I called a local car audio shop and asked if they could install an AUX adaptor such as this:

[image]

They said they can install one if the head unit is aftermarket, but they can't do it for a factory head unit.

Older models of the Lancer have the same head unit screen and the same interface as my 2017. My guess is that Mitsubishi have used the same interface and software for the 2017 model, but didn't include the AUX input that the older models had.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know if this car model does have an AUX input?
2. Is it possible to install an AUX adaptor to a factory head unit? Why would the car shop tell me they can't do it on a factory head unit?

Comment: I'm not sure how similar they are, I used to own a lancer 08 model and also didn't had aux input although you could select it from the interface. After a bit of search I found witch pins on the back of the head unit was meant to be used for aux input and I created my own solution. Since your head unit support it, you have to find a wiring diagram of the head unit and possibly figure out from there witch pins you can use in order to create your own aux cable solution.

Comment: Until now im searching for the solution of the same issue. I have same model as your car.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED IT! Successfully installed an Aux today. I have a stock 2017 ES sport Lancer and wanted to put an Aux in, looked everywhere and couldn't find one already installed, after days of googling I just decided to wing it and found that it's not I stalled stock to the car, probably because they have the Bluetooth in it

On the small White 18 pin connector to the head unit when you are looking at the back of the plug there are 4 empty plug pins, the bottom left is earth, the one directly along next to it is right and the directly above that is left
I didn't take any pictures but if you need more information let me know